# why wildcard doesn't work in `sudo rm` statement?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard, sudo

I was trying to delete all files in log directory and using default bash shell on CentOS 6.5

```
[lei@ids7gueywjZ /]$ sudo ls -al /var/log/jenkins/
total 1541512
drwxr-x---   2 jenkins jenkins       4096 Jul 22 09:52 .
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root    root          4096 Jul 14 21:27 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins      31483 Jul 22 17:07 jenkins.log
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins 1073606656 Jul 18 03:16 jenkins.log-20150718
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins  504815011 Jul 19 03:30 jenkins.log-20150719.gz
[lei@ids7gueywjZ /]$ sudo rm -r /var/log/jenkins/*
rm: cannot remove `/var/log/jenkins/*': No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why `rm -r /var/log/jenkins/*` doesn't work? Is there some default shell configuration I was missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The wildcard expansion is done by the shell, prior to actually calling `sudo`. And the shell itself does not have (or get) `sudo` rights, so it cannot read the contents of `/var/log/jenkins/`.

By the time `rm` (now bestowed with sudo rights) sees its arguments, wildcard expansion has already happened -- or rather, it has not, because there was nothing (readable by the shell) to match that `*`.

So `rm` attempts to delete the **file** (not the wildcard) `/var/log/jenkins/*` -- which does not exist:

> rm: cannot remove `/var/log/jenkins/*': No such file or directory

To get around this, you need a *shell* with `sudo` rights executing your `rm`:

```
sudo sh -c 'rm /var/log/jenkins/*'
```

Now the shell itself gets `sudo`ed, and can do the expansion prior to calling `rm`.

Comment: @LeoShi: The moral here is, "read the error message *carefully*, and take it *literally*". I admit I was a bit lost at first as well. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The directory `/var/log/jenkins` has no rights for "other". Even if you run `sudo rm -r /var/log/jenkins/*`, the shell expansion is done by your user. You should either remove the whole direcotry (`suro rm -r /var/log/jenkinks`), or do everything as the appropriate user (I'd recommend `su`-ing with `jenkins` user).